Change Java path in Android Studio
I want to change the Java path in Android Studio but cannot do it. How to change it?
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A127F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



Set the JAVA_HOME variable path in environment variables till \bin only. Eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\

It is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin', but still not working. Still it goes to Java 21.

If the solution given in the comments is not working. Then you can change the java path from the settings as well.
Follow the steps to change the path

Open file menu
Select settings
Go to Build, Execution and developement
Open Build Tools then select Gradle
In this change the gradle JDK path


